# Old message is not removing in iPhone notification try

Tags: ios, ionic3, phonegap-pushplugin, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am using push plugin in ionic 3 app, everything is working fine but from my server end we are sending one message at a time and im receiving message to iPhone, but old message should overwrite with new message or once we receive new message then old message is clear automatically..
I'm not able to find anything related to this, please anybody help me to solve this.

```
 const options: PushOptions = {
 android: {},
 ios: {
   alert: 'true',
   badge: true,
   sound: 'false'
  },
 windows: {},
 browser: {
     pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
  }
};

const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);


pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => 
console.log('Received a notification', notification));
```

Comment: Can you post the server message payload?  I assume you have a `apns-collapse-id` field in your message payload?

Comment: @BRass here is my payload from server  Title: "Face Notification"
click_action: "FCMPluginActivity"
coldstart: false
foreground: true
rawdata: "{data}"

Comment: There is no apns-collapse-id in the payload

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't sending your messages configured to be "collapsible".  By default each message will be distinct, not overwriting the last message.  FCM documents this well:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

> **Non-collapsible and collapsible messages**
>
> A non-collapsible message
>   denotes that each individual message is delivered to the device. A
>   non-collapsible message delivers some useful content, as opposed to a
>   collapsible message like a content-free "ping" to the mobile app to
>   contact the server to fetch data.
>
> ...
>
> A collapsible message is a message that may be replaced by a new message if it has yet to be delivered to the device.
>
> ...

[image]

Or if you are not using FCM, [here's a reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) to Apple's APN docs directly.

> To allow the coalescing of similar notifications, you can include a
>   collapse identifier within a notification request. Normally, when a
>   device is online, each notification request that you send to APNs
>   results in a notification delivered to the device. However, when the
>   apns-collapse-id key is present in your HTTP/2 request header, APNs
>   coalesces requests whose value for that key is the same. For example,
>   a news service that sends the same headline twice could use the same
>   collapse identifier value for both requests. APNs would then coalesce
>   the two requests into a single notification for delivery to the
>   device. For details on the apns-collapse-id key

**Update with some code details:**

```
public void sendMessage(String title, String body, Map<String, String> data, boolean shouldCollapse) {          

        PlatformConfiguration platformConfig = new PlatformConfiguration(30);

        if (shouldCollapse)
            messageBuilder.setAndroidConfig(platformConfig.getCollapsibleAndroidConfig("test")).setApnsConfig(platformConfig.getCollapsibleApnsConfig("test"));
```

...

```
    public ApnsConfig getCollapsibleApnsConfig(String collapseKey) {

        return getCoreApnsConfig().putHeader("apns-collapse-id", collapseKey)
                .setAps(getNonCollapsibleApsBuilder().setCategory(collapseKey).setThreadId(collapseKey).build()).build();
    }

    public AndroidConfig getCollapsibleAndroidConfig(String collapseKey) {

        return getCoreAndroidConfig().setCollapseKey(collapseKey)
                .setNotification(
                        getNonCollapsibleAndroidNotificationBuilder().setTag(collapseKey).build()).build();
    }
```

Comment: sorry for late reply.. If I send apns-collapse-id then alerts are not coming.. Can u please share what is the exact payload for iOS?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write this layer for us.  Another developer based his "collapse" messages for Apple on these docs.

Comment: Code is code.  I found and attached.  This is clearly just test/POC work for us, primarily following the docs linked to above.